# form_tag not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've added a method to my controller and routed it correctly but when I try to call it from a `form_tag` it give me a router error. What's going on?

```
<% form_tag search_item_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name , '' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
resources :items do
   collection do
      get :search, :as => :search
   end
end
```

rake routes also ok:

```
search_item GET    /items/:id/search(.:format)                        {:action=>"search", :controller=>"items"}
      items GET    /items(.:format)                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"items"}
            POST   /items(.:format)                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"items"}
   new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"items"}
  edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"items"}
       item GET    /items/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items"}
            PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"items"}
            DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"items
```

However, if I write something like this works:

```
<% form_tag url_for(:controller => "items" , :action => "search"), :method => "get" do %>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it should be pluralized `search_items_path`

And routes could be little cleaner

```
resources :items do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

or

```
resources :items do
  get :search, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: I did remove the `as => :search` and yes, it is a plural name `search_items_path`. I've tried `search_item_path` that's why not worked for the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is looking for an `id`, and must be called with `search_item_path(@item)`?

Something is not right there.  With the routes.rb you gave, it should look like:

```
search_items GET /items/search(.:format)
```

Are we seeing everything here?  Your sample defines a collection route but the output of your routes.rb shows it as a member route.

Comment: exactly, so why is it expecting an id?